# nsuser user ID is not properly defined to the system. Aborting install

Tags: solaris, installation-package, iplanet

I am trying to install iPlanet pacakage on a Solaris dev box using pkgadd. When I run it it gives me "nsuser user ID is not properly defined to the system.  Aborting install." and installation fails. 
I am not sure what the error really means and how to fix it. I t would be a great help if someone could point me to the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you create a "nsuser" account ? What Solaris version is this ? What iPlanet package ? How old is it ?

Comment: How do I create a nsuser account? I think my problem will be solved if i can do this. it's Solaris 10. iPlanet 6.1 sp16.

Comment: I didn't wrote you need to create one, just asking if you did. Let me rephrase it: is there an nsuser account on your system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the installation script checks for nsuser in /etc/passwd and nsgroup in /etc/group. I edited those files to add nsuser and nsgroup.

in /etc/passwd i added
nsuser:x:(nsuser id):(nsgroup id):(user name):/home/nsuser:/usr/bin/ksh

in /etc/group I added
nsgroup::(group id):nsuser

And that's it. Re installed the package and it works.